# setxkbmap swap ctrl and tab keys

Tags: xkb

I am currently using `setxkbmap` with the following options

```bsh
setxkbmap -option caps:swapescape
setxkbmap -option altwin:swap_lalt_lwin
```

Now I want to add the following swap <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>L_Ctrl</kbd>. However, nowhere in internet I find a reference to the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key (which is odd); I am even not sure that `tab` is the name XKB guys use.

Does anybody knows how to do the swap?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just for future reference but still pending for a better answer, after reading excellent Archlinux wiki [post](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xorg/Keyboard_configuration#Using_setxkbmap), I

1. used `xkbcomp $DISPLAY output.xkb` to obtain current my current configuration
2. swapped keycodes in output.xkb textfile with the key values identified with `xev -event keyboard`.
3. test new configuration with `xkbcomp input.xkb $DISPLAY`
4. Final file version is named ~/.Xkeymap and I sourced in a script file with `test -f ~/.Xkeymap && xkbcomp ~/.Xkeymap $DISPLAY`